# Check if a custom post type has already been created

Tags: posts, customization

I am creating a plugin that creates a new custom post type. How can I check if the custom post type has been created already (maybe by the user in functions.php for some other use)? Actually I would like to know what is the best way to go about it, maybe add a prefix to my custom post type to make it as unique as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for the existence of a post type, use [`post_type_exists`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_exists). For instance like this:

```
if ( ! post_type_exists( 'yourpt' ) {
     $args = array(
         // your new post type's arguments
     );
     register_post_type( 'yourpt', $args )
}
```

As for the prefix, that's a matter of personal taste and how common you think the post type otherwise is. Personally, I don't think it's necessary.